# Get People from Google+ Circles iOS

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-signin, google-authentication, google-people-api

I am trying to retrieve people in user's circles. Since GPPSignin is depricated I am using GIDSignIn for login. But authentication provided by GIDSignIn is of type GIDAuthentication which can not be used in GTLServicePlus

I  have successfully signed in using GIDSignInButton. Here is my code to retrieve people list

```
GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] autorelease];
plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

[plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];  //Problem is here
 GTLQueryPlus *query =
 [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                                collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];
[plusService executeQuery:query
    completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                        GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed,
                        NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
          GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
          // Get an array of people from GTLPlusPeopleFeed
          NSArray* peopleList = [peopleFeed.items retain];
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @AlexanderVolkov I am currently manually creating GTMOAuth2Authentication object and assigning it all the necessary fields, clientID, userEmail, userID, accessToken, refreshToken, expirationDate. It is working for the time being.

Comment: So, you are using both frameworks - old Goolge Plus SDK and Google Sign-In, correct? Can you please provide an example? Have you tried to use Google Plus Web API or?

Comment: Yeah I am using both frameworks together. For login I use Google Sign-in for G+ Operations I use the Google+ framework. I am posting my current code in answers

Answer (score 0):

So I am currently solving this problem by manually creating GTMOAuth2Authentication object and assigning it the required values. This is my current code.

```
func fetchGPlusContacts() {

    let plusService = GTLServicePlus()
    plusService.retryEnabled = true

    let user = signIn.currentUser
    let auth = GTMOAuth2Authentication()

    auth.clientID = signIn.clientID
    auth.userEmail = user.profile.email
    auth.userID = user.userID
    auth.accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken
    auth.refreshToken = user.authentication.refreshToken
    auth.expirationDate = user.authentication.accessTokenExpirationDate

    plusService.authorizer = auth

    let query = GTLQueryPlus.queryForPeopleListWithUserId("me", collection: kGTLPlusCollectionConnected) as! GTLQueryPlus


    plusService.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, peopleFeed, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("error: \(error.description)")

            if (self.delegate != nil) {
                if self.delegate?.failedFetchFriendsFromGoogle != nil {
                    self.delegate!.failedFetchFriendsFromGoogle!(error)
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if let peopleFd = peopleFeed as? GTLPlusPeopleFeed {
                var items : [GTLPlusPerson] = []
                if let itms = peopleFd.items() as? [GTLPlusPerson] {
                    items = itms
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am still looking for the right way to perform this task.